# Parsing ints from text file into constructor in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, constructor, readfile

I was hoping that someone can help me with the following issue that I am having. I have a class that reads a file with numbers like this:

> 7, 2
>   35, 6
>   6, 2

and so on. The numbers represent x and y coordinates. 
Here is what I am trying to do:

```
try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(file));
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        scan.nextLine();
        cities++;
    }

    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(new File(file));
    scan1.useDelimiter(",");

    for (int i = 0; i < cities; i = i + 1) {
        City city = new City(scan1.nextInt(), scan1.nextInt(););
        TourHandler.addCity(city);


    }
    return City.getCities();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}
```

The constructor from the City class

```
  public City(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
```

I am trying to add the numbers into `x` and `y` of the `City` class, but for some reason it doesn't work. My guess is that the problem is somewhere around here:

```
City city = new City(scan1.nextInt(), scan1.nextInt());
```

My problem is that I cannot parse them in the constructor of the other class. I am getting the following result `[7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]`. the `nextInt` does not move from the first int of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many semicolons in your code.

Change your line

```
City city = new City(scan1.nextInt(), scan1.nextInt(););
```

To

```
City city = new City(scan1.nextInt(), scan1.nextInt());
```

You need a semicolon at the end of your "statement" - the whole line in your case. You cannot put semicolons in the middle of your statement like you did - the compiler thinks that you wanted to end your statement, but you cannot at that point because the opening `(` and closing `)` parentheses don't balance out yet at the first semicolon, so you get an error message.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. This doesn't fix my problem though.

Comment: @zerox33 You didn't describe your problem in much detail. With the semicolon in it, your code doesn't compile. Are there more problems after fixing this? Please describe (edit your question)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what some of your classes are (you didn't provide an MCVE) and what everything is supposed to do, but I can help you parse the coordinates. I simulated your file as a string and gave that to the scanner instead.

Using your way of 2 `Scanner`s, the first one reads each line and the second one splits it using the given delimiter:

```
public class Rainers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String file = "1, 2\n" + "3, 4\n" + "5, 6";

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String coords = scan.nextLine();
            Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(coords);
            scan2.useDelimiter(", ");
            int x = scan2.nextInt();
            int y = scan2.nextInt();
            System.out.println(x + ", " + y);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need 2 scanners. Use `String#split` and then parse each one to an `int`:

```
public class Rainers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String file = "1, 2\n" + "3, 4\n" + "5, 6";

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String coords = scan.nextLine();
            String[] parsedCoords = coords.split(", ");
            int x = Integer.parseInt(parsedCoords[0]);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(parsedCoords[1]);
            System.out.println(x + ", " + y);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> 1, 2
>   3, 4
>   4, 5